# "С тех пор как я + глагол в настоящем времени". Является ли такая конструкция грамматически правильной?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы

Обычно можно услышать:

> С тех пор как я *вернулся* на работу, я чувствую себя прекрасно.
>
> С тех пор как я *узнал* об этом, мне очень хочется рассказать вам
> правду.

То есть глагол ставят в прошедшем времени. Но мне стало интересно, а считаются ли следующие предложения грамматически правильными:

> С тех пор как я [нахожусь] на работе, я чувствую себя прекрасно.
>
> С тех пор как я знаю об этом, мне очень хочется рассказать вам правду.
>
> Прошло совсем немного времени с тех пор, как вы [находитесь] с нами.
>
> Прошло всего пару месяцев с тех пор, как вы [находитесь] на работе.

Я нашел лишь один пример из текста Бориса Гребенщикова, который использует глагол в настоящем времени в подобной конструкции:

> С тех пор, как я *знаю* тебя, мне не нужен никто другой.

Является ли такая конструкция грамматически правильной?

Comment: *Прошло всего пару месяцев,* да? Ксения, привет!

Answer (score 5):

Конструкция "с тех пор как я + глагол в настоящем времени" сама по себе безупречна с точки зрения грамматики, но многое зависит от контекста. В монографии Н.Ю. Шведовой "Русская грамматика" эта конструкция рассматривается отдельно и подробно объясняется (с многочисленными примерами).

> В предложениях с союзом *с тех пор как* признак следования осложнен
> специфическим ограничением: ситуация, о которой сообщается в главном
> предложении, осуществляется в такой период времени, обе границы
> которого обозначены: начало этого периода отодвинуто в прошлое (*с тех
> пор*), а конечная граница совпадает с моментом речи. Таким образом,
> значение следования, выражаемое союзом *с тех пор как*, сопровождается
> значением двустороннего ограничения
> **с тех пор — до сих пор**: *С тех пор, как мы знаем друг друга, ты ничего мне не дал, кроме страданий (Лерм.); С тех пор, как ты стоишь
> под небесами, Такого сына не рождала ты И в недра не брала свои
> обратно (Некр.); Картину эту я помню с тех пор, как помню самого себя;
> С тех пор как я учусь в институте, у меня нет ни минуты свобод- ного
> времени; С тех пор как мы знакомы, мы всегда спорим; С тех пор как он
> занимается плаванием, он перестал болеть.*
>
> Предложения, в которых **придаточная часть имеет значение наст. вр.**,
> особенно отчетливо выявляют семантическую специфику союза *с тех пор*
> как: наст. вр. одновременно со своим основным значением указывает на
> обращенность начала ситуации в прошлое. Фрагмент *с тех пор как мы
> знакомы* передает информацию
> **с того момента как началось и продолжается наше знакомство**; фрагмент *с тех пор как он занимается плаванием* — информацию **с тех
> пор как он начал и продолжает заниматься плаванием**.

Отдельно замечу, что варианты "с тех пор как мы познакомились" и "с тех пор как мы знакомы" могут сильно отличаться по смыслу.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129780/discussion-on-answer-by-grizzly---------).

Answer (score 3):

Настоящее время возможно, но лишь изредка. Это зависит от глагола. Возможно, что это пришло из английского, где подобное часто. Пример, когда фактическое время и временная форма глагола не совпадают:
*Завтра я работаю.*

"С" указывает на точку в прошлом, с которой всё началось, поэтому и глагол в прошедшем времени. Но порой можно отступать от этой нормы. Больше это связано с разговорными традициями, как в примере выше, где строгие нормы как бы легально нарушаются.

Здесь больше надо говорить о нарушении стилистики, а не грамматики.

*С тех пор как я [нахожусь] на работе, я чувствую себя прекрасно.* || Звучит так, что он живёт на работе, постоянно там. Надо так:
*С тех пор как я работаю, я чувствую себя прекрасно.* || Так люди говорят.

*С тех пор как я знаю об этом, мне очень хочется рассказать вам правду.* || А вот так уже не говорят. Необходимо "узнал". Повторюсь, что зависит от глагола.

Так тоже не говорят, нарушения стилистики, хоть и не критические — "прошло всего пару месяцев" указывает на временную точку, которую необходимо обозначить глаголом прошедшего времени (чтоб было грамотно):
*Прошло совсем немного времени с тех пор, как вы с нами.* || Вариант замены: *как вы присоединились к нам*.
*Прошло всего пару месяцев с тех пор, как вы на работе.* || Вариант замены: *как вы приcтупили к работе*.

*С тех пор, как я знаю тебя, мне не нужен никто другой.* || Допустимо. "Узнал" вообще не подходит.

Авторитетный пример с Грамоты:
*Никогда с тех пор, как свет стоит, ни один флот не испытывал более глупого и жалкого поражения.* В. Шукшин, Чужие. || Здесь настоящее время звучит художественно, красиво. "Начал стоять" не подходит.

Update:
Почему говорю о разговорных традициях? "С тех пор" должно указать на пору в прошлом, с которой всё началось, глаголом в прошедшем времени, сам по себе предлог "с" указывает на начало, а не на всё. Но люди обошли это ограничение и расширили употребление глаголов. Если уж указывать на весь период, то, по идее, должно быть "за те поры, что" (как и "за то время, что"), но сложилось иначе.

Comment: *Возможно, что это пришло из английского, где подобное часто* — а можно пример? По-моему, как раз всё наоборот!

Comment: Когда говорят: I will say if I find (вместо *I will find*). Я в общем про использование  настоящего вместо других времён. *По-моему, как раз всё наоборот!* — наоборот? Английский будет перенимать что-то с русского? Когда такое было?

Comment: Да не английский с русского, а время там прошедшее! *I've known him since he was a child.* А 'say' без объекта не бывает (что сказать, кому может ещё подразумеваться).

Comment: Да не, я в общем говорю про то, когда настоящее используют в английском вместо других времён, а не конкретно о данном случае.

Comment: Про "say" не понял.

Comment: "It has only been a couple of months since you've been on the job" - в английском возможны такие предложения; в обеих частях настоящее перфектное время. На русский можно перевести как: "[К настоящему моменту] прошло всего пару месяцев с тех пор, как вы на работе" или "...приступили к работе".

Comment: @ Rusletov А почему не перевести на русский как «Прошло всего парА месяцев с тех пор, как вы РАБОТАЕТЕ»?

Comment: @Егор Сальков Хорошее замечание. Благодарю!

Comment: @ЕгорСальков Говорят "всего парУ месяцев". Похожий пример: *пару дней назад*.

Comment: @ЕгорСальков: только не "прошло", а "прошла". Я на это же и намекал в своём комментарии по вашим вопросом. Oleedd, нельзя сказать I'll say, можно только I'll say something (to someone).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да не, там смысл "скажу, если найду". Буквально: *скажу про то, что нашёл, если найду* — нет, так не пойдёт. *Прошла всего пара месяцев* — согласование понятно, но разве так говорят? "Пару" имеет значение "несколько" (примерное количество), что указано в словаре, а "пара" — это конкретно два.

Comment: В словаре не указано, что "пару" означает "несколько", а "пара" — нет. Про падеж и речи нету, это было бы абсурдно. 'Say' не подходит, должно быть *I'll tell you if I find it.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да, с "tell" хорошо звучит, сразу заметил, что "say" не сильно подходит. Ясно, что "пара" в значении "два" может быть в падеже: *хочу пару (комплект), а не один*. Бери и читай словарь, примеры в помощь, у нас значение 7a: https://i.imgur.com/D8fmIgp.png

Comment: *а "пара" — нет* — давай пример, где тоже значение "несколько", это сомнительно.

Comment: Ну вот этот пример есть, который ты не признал пока, а из словаря пока дать не могу.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Такие примеры? *Прошла всего пара месяцев. Прошла всего пара дней. Прошла всего пара минут. Прошла всего пара секунд. Прошла всего пара лет.* У вас так говорят? У нас — нет. Обрати внимание на последний пример, он самый ужасный. У вас точно так говорят? Или корректны все, или не корректно ничего.

Comment: Я уже начал сомневаться)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Это как мне хотелось сказать "потратил куч**а** времени", если помнишь, да и сейчас мне так больше нравится, потому что сталкивался именно с этим вариантом. Можно заменить на "куча часов", и будет такое же.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Газета «Известия» для вас авторитет? :) 2002.03.17: «Заметно, как он уже превращается в трущобы, ветшает на глазах, хотя прошло всего пара лет после застройки».

Comment: Авторитет — не авторитет, но так неправильно звучит. ;)